# Desktop path on mac

Tags: macos, safari

I want create a file on the desk top of client mac machine from my website.but the desktop path is changed based on the user.How i get machine desk top pathe from my website.

In mac desktop path is like /Users/username/Desktop, but the username is changed by machine to machine.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to put a file on the user's desktop, there's no other way than have him download it. You can't access the filesystem, this is a basic security thing.

Comment: As I said you can't access the filesystem from a webpage, this means there is no way to put a file on the user's desktop.

Answer (score 4):

`~/Desktop` can be used as a shorthand to access the Desktop folder for the current user.