# Unable to encrypt and decrypt data in plist

Tags: ios, encryption, plist, rncryptor

I'm trying to encrypt the saved plist data using RNCryptor and decrypt it.
the output is all gibberish in encrypted file but am not able to get the anything after decryption.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"data.plist"]];
NSError *error1;

bac = [RNEncryptor encryptData:data withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings password:@"abcdef" error:&error1];

NSString *pathToDesktop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/rajparmar/Desktop/encrypt.plist"];
[bac writeToFile:pathToDesktop atomically:YES];
```

Here is the code for decryption

NSError *error1;

```
    NSData *decryptedData = [RNDecryptor decryptData:bac
                                        withPassword:@"abcdef"
                                               error:&error1];
    NSString *pathToDesktop1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/rajparmar/Desktop/decrypt.plist"];
    [decryptedData writeToFile:pathToDesktop1 atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Check [desktop-path-on-mac](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731566/desktop-path-on-mac) is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complete Example with code using RNEncryptor and RNDecryptor.

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
    #import <Security/Security.h>
    #import "RNCryptor/RNEncryptor.h"
    #import "RNCryptor/RNDecryptor.h"

    @interface ViewController () {

        UILabel* lable;
        NSMutableDictionary* plistDict;
    }

    @end

    @implementation ViewController

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UIButton* btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 60);
        btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [btn1 setTitle:@"SaveData" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn1.center = self.view.center;
        [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(saveDataToPlist:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn1];

        UIButton* btn2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        btn2.frame = CGRectMake(btn1.frame.origin.x, btn1.frame.origin.y + 100, 150, 60);
        btn2.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        [btn2 setTitle:@"Show Data" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [btn2 addTarget:self action:@selector(getDataFromPlist:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:btn2];

        lable = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(btn2.frame.origin.x, btn2.frame.origin.y + 100, 300, 40)];
        lable.text = @"";
        [self.view addSubview:lable];

        //create plist if not exits
        [self createPlistIfNotExists];
    }

    #pragma mark - Button Events
    - (void)saveDataToPlist:(id)sender
    {

        NSString* eString = @"Hello World How are you";
        [self insertEncryptedDataIntoPlist:eString forKey:@"ENData"];
    }

    - (void)getDataFromPlist:(id)sender
    {
        NSString* dString = [self decryptDataFromPlistForKey:@"ENData"];
        [lable setText:dString];
    }

    #pragma mark - Encryption and Decryption

    - (void)insertEncryptedDataIntoPlist:(NSString*)aDataString forKey:(NSString*)aKey
    {

        NSError* error;
        NSData* data;

        data = [RNEncryptor encryptData:[aDataString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                           withSettings:kRNCryptorAES256Settings
                               password:@"@ABC123"
                                  error:&error];
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed: %@", error);
            exit(1);
        }

        [plistDict setObject:data forKey:aKey];
        [plistDict writeToFile:[self getPlistPath] atomically:YES];
    }

    - (NSString*)decryptDataFromPlistForKey:(NSString*)aKey
    {

        NSMutableDictionary* savedStock = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self getPlistPath]];
        NSError* error;
        NSData* data;

        data = [RNDecryptor decryptData:[[NSData alloc] initWithData:[savedStock valueForKey:aKey]] withPassword:@"@ABC123" error:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Failed: %@", error);
            exit(1);
        }

        NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        return string;
    }

    - (void)createPlistIfNotExists
    {
        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"eplist.plist"];
        NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eplist.plist"]];
        }

        if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
            plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
        }
        else {
            // If the file doesn’t exist, create an empty dictionary
            plistDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        }
    }

    - (NSString*)getPlistPath
    {
        NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"eplist.plist"];
        return path;
    }

    @end
```

Comment: how to give path ? is my code correct ? I'm not getting anything in decrypted file

Comment: According to line, 
NSData *data = [@"Data" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


its encoding word @"Data", how can i encrypt my entire plist file.
my plist file name is data.plist.

Comment: iam passing string to encode for assumption i have taken @"Data" string to encode.

Comment: okay. how do I encrypt entire data.plist ? and yes I'm working on iOS